# python: import Class but get error cannot import name or 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I'm trying to use this file on github: https://github.com/alex314159/blpapiwrapper

The file starts off like this:

```
class BLP():
```

and the filename is blpapiwrapper.py

So I created a new file, blptest.py, and I start the file with:

```
from blpapiwrapper import BLP
```

but when I try to run the file, it says (, ImportError('cannot import name BLP',), None)

I also tried just

```
import blpapiwrapper 
bloomberg = blpapiwrapper.BLP()
```

but then I get the error message: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BLP'`

I tried creating an empty `__init__.py` file since that's what I read on StackExchange but it still didn't work.

I moved the blpapiwrapper.py file into the same folder as blptest.py.

Comment: Can you show us your map-structure?

Comment: All the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Are you create `init.py` or `__init__.py` file?

Comment: I'm creating the init.py with underscores but when I type the underscores in they disappear on this website

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this error, because the way you have written it `(, ImportError('cannot import name BLP',), None)` tells me you are running this file in some non-standard way.

Comment: I was running line-by-line in PyCharm which executes in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. The folder and the filename were the same, blpapiwrapper, so when I imported python thought I was referring to the folder. Once I deleted the folder everything started to work. Thanks everyone!